# How is it that the Cauchy Integral Formula is used when a singular point exists inside a closed curve?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

So I'm trying to evaluate the integral 
$$\oint_{|z|=3} \frac{e^{iz}}{z+i} dz$$ 
using the Cauchy Integral Formula.

But clearly, the point at $z=-i$ is a singular point, which exists inside our circle  $|z|=3$. And this is where I'm confused.

Certainly, the singularity point at $-i$  means $f(z)$ is not analytic everywhere inside our curve since it is undefined at $-i$ .

But according to my textbook, we can apply the Cauchy Integral Formula. But how? The function is not analytic everywhere interior, but this is a condition to use the Cauchy formula. So why is the textbook saying that I can use the Cauchy formula? What am I missing here?

Comment: Think about integrating $f(z) = 1/z$ over any circle centered at the origin. We get $2\pi i$, and this is a special case of the integral formula.

Comment: If the function were analytic everywhere inside the curve, the integral would be 0 (this is a special case of Cauchy's formula).

Comment: Cauchy Integral Formula $\ne$ Cauchy Integral Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) says: $$\oint_{\gamma}\frac {f(z)}{z-z_0}dz=2\pi i \cdot f(z_0),$$ where $f(z)$ is analytic in an open set containing the curve $\gamma$ ( taken counter-clockwise) and its interior, and $z_0$ is a point inside $\gamma$.

So in your case we can take $f(z)=e^{iz}$ which in analytic in $\mathbb{C}$, and $z_0=-i$ which is inside the circle $|z|=3$.